# Rails 3 ActionMailer localized views fallbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I'm using ActionMailer in my application and I want to use localized views for email templates. It seems to work as expected, but it doesn't provide any fallback. For example, I want to send an email in Russian. The mailer method name is called *invite*. So, ActionMailer will search for invite.ru.html.erb and invite.ru.text.erb. If it doesn't find these templates, it sends just empty emails, but I'm expecting it to send invite.en.html.erb and invite.en.text.erb . I messed with ActionView::LookupContext#skip_default_locale!, but it doesn't work as I'm expecting it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use invite.html.erb instead of invite.default_local.html.erb

Comment: Well, in this situation it renders initially the Russian templates, and then it renders default_locale templates, so finally I receive emails in default_locale.